# Trigger prevents insertion of data into table

Tags: postgresql, function, stored-procedures, triggers, insert

I have the following problem:
I'm trying to insert data into a table, however my Trigger is preventing me from performing the insert. My trigger is to insert the codigolle into a log table when a given 'year' <'2000' is entered, but I'm encountering the following error:

" ERROR: query has no destination for result data
  HINT: If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
  CONTEXT: PL / pgSQL function funcaotriggerxx () line 5 at SQL statement "

TRIGGER

```
CREATE FUNCTION funcaoTriggerXX() RETURNS trigger AS $valor$
DECLARE
    cod INT;
BEGIN
    SELECT codigolivro 
    FROM edicao
    WHERE ano < '2000';

    cod = codigolivro;

    INSERT INTO log (codigolivro) VALUES (cod);

    RETURN cod;
END;
$valor$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER codigoLivros AFTER INSERT ON edicao
EXECUTE PROCEDURE funcaoTriggerXX();
```

PROCEDURE

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION seculoxx()
RETURNS integer AS $total2$
declare
    total2 integer;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) into total2 
   FROM edicao
   WHERE ano < 2000;
   RETURN total2;
END;
$total2$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

SELECT

```
SELECT seculoxx();
```

INSERT

```
INSERT INTO edicao (codigolivro, numero, ano) VALUES ('1325','4','1990');
```

The structure of the table is also simple:
edicao

- code (numeric)
- Version (character)
- Year (integer)

log

- codigolivro

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your trigger function says it returns `trigger` (NULL/OLD/NEW) when it actually returns an `INTEGER`. Then as the error says, you can't do a `SELECT` in a plpgsql function without a destination. In other words, you need to assign the result of your `SELECT` statement to a variable.

```
SELECT codigolivro 
    INTO cod
FROM edicao
WHERE ano < '2000';
```

Your `seculoxx()` function is fine but doesn't need the intermediate variable:

```
RETURN count(*)
FROM edicao
WHERE ano < 2000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at how your select queries in `funcaoTriggerXX` and `seculoxx` differ. When you want to store a value from from a select query you need to `SELECT column_name INTO variable_name`. When you don't want to save the result then you need use `PERFORM`. eg. `PERFORM SELECT ...`.

There's also a discrepancy between your language and what code will do. That is you say:

> My trigger is to insert the codigolle into a log table when a given 'year' <'2000' is entered

I presume you mean the `codigolivro` for the row that was just inserted. However, as it stands. This trigger will essentially insert a random row with `year < 2000` if **any** row in the `edicao` table meets that condition.
Instead, you can use the `NEW` special variable to get the row that was just inserted, and you can use the `WHEN` clause of `CREATE TRIGGER` to control when your trigger fires.

Since you only care about the row that has just been inserted (not all rows in the entire table), then you can use the `NEW` special variable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION funcaoTriggerXX() RETURNS trigger AS $valor$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO log (codigolivro) VALUES (NEW.codigolivro);
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$valor$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER codigoLivros AFTER INSERT ON edicao
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.ano < 2000)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE funcaoTriggerXX();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I am learning these functions now, your tips will be useful for future problems!